# WPF C# Derived UserControl Net Core Namespace Does Not Exist

Tags: wpf, .net-core, user-controls, derived

I'm trying to migrate a C# WPF application from 4.8 Framework to Net Core 3.1 on VS2019/Windows 11. My build fails :

> Error XDG0008 The name "UserControlBase" does not exist in the
> namespace
> "clr-namespace:WpfApp2".  WpfApp2 \UserControl2.xaml    Line 1

My UserControls are derived from a base class that itself is derived from UserControl. E.g.

```
<local:UserControlBase x:Class="WpfApp2.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
            
    </Grid>
</local:UserControlBase>
```

Then the UserControlBase class is like this:

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    public class UserControlBase : UserControl
    {
    }
}
```

My proj file for this demo application is thus:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

UserControls declared like "<UserControl x:Class=WpfApp2.UserControl1..." and "public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl..." compile without issue.

Any ideas how to overcome this?  My derived usercontrols are done this way to allow them to be used in a factory type way & be created in code behind when needed by the end-user. It's pretty fundamental to the application.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Why are you using net core rather than net 6?

Comment: Not supported in VS2019 afaik. Any ideas on the compilation issue?